# Use the properties of determinants to find the value of the second determinant, given the value of the first

Tags: linear-algebra

Given:
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}s&t&u\\ v&w&x\\ 4&2&8 \end{bmatrix} = 3$$

Find the value of: 
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}32-s&16-t&64-u\\ v&w&x\\4&2&8 \end{bmatrix}$$

The options are:

a. -24

b. -3

c. 24

d. 3

How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By subtracting $8$ times the third row to the first one you have $$\det\begin{bmatrix}32-s&16-t&64-u\\ v&w&x\\4&2&8\end{bmatrix}=\det\begin{bmatrix}-s&-t&-u\\ v&w&x\\4&2&8\end{bmatrix}=-\det\begin{bmatrix}s&t&u\\ v&w&x\\4&2&8\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Determinant does not change when you add or subtract multiples of rows from each other. What happens if you subtract 8*(last row) from the first row? Can you finish transforming the matrix to the same one?

Answer (score 0):

Write the formula of the first derminant and the formula of the second one, then use the first formula to find the value of the second determinant.